# OpenTelemetry Scope vs. spanBuilder.startSpan() and span.end()

Tags: java, open-telemetry

When using the OTel Java API, manually instrumented code typically looks like the following:

```java
@Inject
Tracer tracer;

public String instrumentedMethod() {
  // ...
  Span span = tracer.spanBuilder("interesting operation").startSpan();
  span.setAttribute("custom.info", "some info");
  try (Scope scope = span.makeCurrent()) {
    // logic
  }
  finally {
    span.end();
  }
  // ...
}
```

From my point of view, the lifespan of the `span` is defined twice:

- `tracer.spanBuilder("...").startSpan()` and `span.end()` demarcate the beginning and the end of the span,
- but also the `span.makeCurrent()` and `scope.end()` does this in some way

What's the purpose of `startSpan()`/`span.end()` in contrast to `span.makeCurrent()`/`scope.end()`. Can `scope` be omitted? Is `span.end()` superfluous when `scope` is used?

Answer (score 4):

Starting and ending a span does not make the rest of your application aware of the current `Context` - i.e. what span is currently "active".

If you didn't open the `Scope`, any code in your `//logic` section would not be able to know the `Context`, and so it can't know what the parent span is. You would end up with a bunch of individual spans that aren't linked together by a common trace.

When you open a `Scope`, OpenTelemetry sets a `ThreadLocal`, and so any new span started within that scope (the `try` block) will be able to know what its parent span is.

There are cases where you may have a `Context` but not an entire `Span`, so those concepts are separated for that reason (and I assume a handful of others reasons).